# Conversion from string (x) to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-2012

doing something for class and i'm completely stuck, even teacher seems unsure. any response appreciated. it's the first printline that is causing problems:
"A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "1: Night F3, 10 tickets purchase" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

```
Dim filename As String
    Dim fridaytickets As Integer
    fridaytickets = 0
    filename = "Z:\Computing Science\S5 (Higher)\Coursework Assessment\output.txt"
    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Output)
    For x = 1 To 300
        If Mid(TicketID(x), 1, 1) = "F" Then
            PrintLine((x) & ": Night " & TicketID(x) & ", " & TicketNo(x) & " tickets purchased. £" & (TicketNo(x) * 10) & " made.")
            fridaytickets = fridaytickets + TicketNo(x)
        End If
        PrintLine(fridaytickets & " were purchased for Friday night.")
        PrintLine("£" & (fridaytickets * 10) & " was made.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the line:

```
PrintLine(fridaytickets & " were purchased for Friday night.")
```

Your `fridaytickets` is an integer, Strangely, it seems that `&` is taken as binary operator, so both side with integer. It should not be so, but maybe it is a bug or version dependent. Or just an overloading of the normal concatenation operator.

In any case, the correct way is to prepare the strings to be concatenated:

```
PrintLine(fridaytickets.toString & " were purchased for Friday night.")
```

Comment: and the same: `x.toString` in the first PrintLine